# Bottom navigation bar, how to show Four Icons with text?

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottomnavigationview

I am using the new bottom navigation bar added in support library 25 i want to show 4 icons with text right now if there are more the 3 items it only shown the active icon with text for others only show the icon.

Right Now it shows Like this

[image]

What i wanted to achieve is this

[image]

I wanted to show four Icons with text as in second screen and it looks right

I know there are third party libraries through which i can achieve this
https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar but i want to do this with support library 25

Note:Second screen shot does not belong to me i have copied it from here 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230653

Comment: It is not currently possible to override this behavior of BottomNavigationView. If you really need this, maybe consider using TabLayout instead with no tab indicator.